# Unable to publish on SNS from ec2 instance without credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I am trying to publish to sns from ec2 instance (a role is associated with this instance, which allows it to publish)

```
$client = new StsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
]);

$roleToAssumeArn = 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/MYSNSROLE';

try {
    $result = $client->assumeRole([
        'RoleArn' => $roleToAssumeArn,
        'RoleSessionName' => 'session1'
    ]);
    // output AssumedRole credentials, you can use these credentials
    // to initiate a new AWS Service client with the IAM Role's permissions
       
    
    $client = new SnsClient([
        'region'      => 'ap-southeast-1',
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'credentials' =>  [
            'key'    => $result['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            'secret' => $result['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            'token'  => $result['Credentials']['SessionToken']
        ]
    ]);
    
    
    return $client;

    
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

When code try to run it shows following error
Cannot read credentials from /home/webapp/.aws/credentials874/var/app/current/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `'Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider'` to create credentials by assuming a role, you need to provide `'client'` information with a `'StsClient'` object and `'assume_role_params'` details, as shown.

```
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider;
use Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider;
use Aws\S3\SnsClient;
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;

// Passing Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider options directly
$profile = new InstanceProfileProvider();
$ARN = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xaccounts3access";
$sessionName = "s3-access-example";

$assumeRoleCredentials = new AssumeRoleCredentialProvider([
    'client' => new StsClient([
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
        'version' => '2011-06-15',
        'credentials' => $profile
    ]),
    'assume_role_params' => [
        'RoleArn' => $ARN,
        'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName,
    ],
]);


$client = new SnsClient([
    'region'      => 'ap-southeast-1',
    'version'     => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials' => $provider
]);
```

Hope this will be helpful.